# Do I need a flyback diode when using a MOSFET in an H-bridge?

Tags: diodes, flyback

I am using an [IRF1404](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irf1404.pdf) power MOSFET and looking at the datasheet I see that the continuous source current (in the Source-Drain ratings section) is rated at 202 A!

I will be using it to drive a wheelchair motor. Do I still need a flyback diode? I mean the internal diode should be more than enough to handle current when the motor is turned off, etc?

[image: Source-drain ratings]

Diagram:

[image: Diagram]

Comment: The internal diode can protect the MOSFET from reverse voltage, but not from overvoltage.

Comment: wouldn't the diode clamp that?

Comment: [Understanding MOSFET Current Ratings](http://www.mcmanis.com/chuck/robotics/projects/esc2/FET-power.html)

Comment: Unless specifically specified in the datasheet, the body diode is not rated for similar currents as the FET itself.

Comment: Also note [footnote 6 in the datasheet](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irf1404.pdf): Calculated continuous current based on maximum allowable junction temperature. Package limitation current is 75A

Comment: @jippie, based on the http://www.irf.com/technical-info/appnotes/an-936.pdf. I will quote the exact line, "The integral body-drain diode is a real circuit element, and its current handling capability is typically as high as that of the transistor itself"

Comment: Correct, but in general you have to double check the datasheet.

Comment: right but when the motor is turned off that current is not continuous. It is instantaneous right?

Comment: The flyback diode is meant to clamp the voltage caused by the interruption of current when the motor is switched off, and is in parallel with the inductance. The body diode of the MOSFET will most likely be (I say most likely, since you haven't specified a schematic) in series with the inductance, so it cannot clamp anything. Sure, there will be a conduction path, but what's limiting the inductor voltage? A discrete clamp diode will de-energize the inductor quickly with minimal stress to the rest of the circuitry.

Comment: @AdamLawrence, Ah! now I get it. You are right the body diode goes across the D-S terminals and flyback across the inductance load. Can you please answer so I can accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: @Tut Why allow the MOSFET to avalanche at all, and why deal with high dv/dt when you can kill it at the winding? Just because the MOSFET *can* handle avalanche doesn't mean it *should* handle it repeatedly. Furthermore, you have to keep the avalanche energy within certain bounds, and without the right equipment it's difficult to accurately characterize the MOSFET stress.

Comment: Actually the body diode would clamp it BUT the current will flow through the supply ! If the supply is capable of handling that reverse current (for example if it has a reverse diode or large supply decoupling) things will be OK. BUT I would not rely on that, just place the flyback diode across the terminals of the motor and be safe. Also, what is more expensive: replace the FET later and add a diode, or placing the diode now ?

Comment: @Tut You will never convince me that allowing a MOSFET to avalanche is better than locally clamping the voltage with an appropriate flyback diode. To me, using an avalanche-rated part is like a small insurance policy on the rating of the device - it's there if I really really need it, but I don't want to operate there if I can help it. In my line of work, avalanche is something to be avoided wherever possible.

Comment: @Tut Now that OP has shown a full-bridge configuration, things are indeed different.

Comment: @AdamLawrence Yes and being a wheelchair motor, I should have anticipated the H-bridge. Since my avalanche comments are now moot, I'm going to delete them.

Comment: @AdamLawrence, can you please explain why things are different?

Comment: See Spehro's answer. You can't put a diode across the inductance in a bridge configuration. Before you added the schematic (and because you were asking about a flyback diode) I incorrectly assumed that you were controlling the motor with a single MOSFET.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a full H-bridge (or half-bridge) the body diode of the *other* MOSFET (the one not switching) will act as a flyback diode, however the power loss may be more than through the MOSFET since the motor run current multiplied by Rds(on) can be less than a diode drop for a good MOSFET.

The Vds will thus be clamped to the battery voltage (plus a volt or two), but take care that there is not too much inductance between the H-bridge and the batteries- otherwise the MOSFETs could see too high a voltage and avalanche. A sturdy TVS right at the bridge (across the power rails) can be a good investment (definition of sturdy depends on how much current and how much inductance).

Obviously **you cannot put a diode directly across the motor** (or it would burn up as soon as the motor is reversed) but you can parallel the MOSFETs with power Schottky diodes. That will reduce the dissipation in the MOSFETs, depending on how you are driving the H-bridge.

As jippie and others have said, the package (wire bonds and such like) limits the drain current to 75A and that's not very conservative. You actually may have troubles with such a modest MOSFET running a wheelchair motor. In particular it will tend to fail when first started because the battery and motor resistances are very low so the peak current can be very high.

I hope if you're making a wheelchair type device you have a **manual override** to disconnect the battery. MOSFETs (like other semis) tend to fail 'on' and I can visualize some unfortunate possibilities.

Comment: A current control loop will help with initial acceleration current. In my practice the external shottkies are used to take some power out of the MOSFETs. Other than that, internal diodes will work fine.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany, This mosfet will fail? How? can you please backup your statement. These motors tend to have power from 200 to 800W. And say I am using a 12V source with a 400W motor then I = 400/12 = 33A. Shouldn't the mosfet be enough to withstand that. The mosfet specs talks about continuous drain current of 200A at 25'C and 143A at 100'C.

Comment: The start up surge for a 600 or 800W DC motor can easily be hundreds of amperes. Look at the motor specs for LRA (locked rotor amps) or divide 12V by the datasheet motor resistance. If the user can 'plug' the motor (reverse it when running) then double that number.

Comment: Does this mean MOSFET is not a good choice? What are my options then? Sorry I am just trying to understand proper circuit design :)

Comment: MOSFETS are really an excellent choice for 12V motors, but you *might* need a beefier one is all I'm saying.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I apologize I'm reviving a near 10y old discussion but I'm suffering from exactly what you have described and I'm not sure how to solve the problem. If OPs motor is 800W 12V then it should have about 150A stall current. If the transistor is rated at 200A continuous, how is that not powerful enough? How can I determine whether a transistor will withstand startup? I have a 36V motor with 0.25 ohms resistance, calculated about 140A stall current, my IRLZ44Ns die instantly. I tried adding a 2ohm 100W resistor in series with the motor and determined that startup current is the killer

Comment: @php_nub_qq  OP did not have a solid limit on the current drawn by their motor. You appear to have. However IRLZ44 are not really capable of 140A. When I worked on a similar project back when we had to use relatively expensive chassis-mount modules to get enough surge capability. You may not need to, but you may need to use 10V drive MOSFETs in TO-247 and a 10V or better gate driver. Maybe something like a IRFP2907PbF or IXFH270N06T3 but note the package and lead current limits and the so-called continuous rating is often under completely unrealistic conditions such as Tc = 25°C.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany so essentially the transistor needs to be massively oversized in order to not burn on start up (using 100% pulse width). I'm assuming its continuous rating has to be greater than the stall current of the motor, is this correct? I just tried running my motor this way with an IRF1405 and it seemed to deal with it no problem, but I'm kind of worried as it is TO-220, I'll probably replace it with a TO-247 one with 150A+ rated current. I'm just adding this comment as it might be useful to someone.

Comment: @php_nub_qq I think that's roughly correct for the continuous rating set by package and die and typical (relatively long in electronics terms) start-up surge duration. The limit for thermal reasons can probably be a bit less conservative. All this can be done by design, the parts should behave as per proper interpretation of the datasheets except maybe SOA curves, which it is worth being very conservative around.